# Get rid of "Bad Event Tracking Code" message in GA

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I use GA to track redirects from my website.
For each redirect I send `event` hit to GA via measurement protocol. I also set the `Document location URL` parameter to some virtual (fake) web address.

In reports, I get "Bad Event Tracking Code" warning because I have `(not set)` entry present in the "Landing Pages" report. I guess it's because I have a lot of sessions that include `event` hits only, without initial `pageview` hits.

This situation is normal, I don't expect to use the landing page report in my view. The thing is that the warning is quite annoying. I don't want to ignore it because it may mask more important problems. I also don't want to send additional `pageview` hit for each redirect.

Is there any elegant way to ignore/dismiss this warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore individual warnings without ignoring all warnings. If you click the ignore button, you'll see you have the option to also only ignore them for a particular time frame.

What you're doing is perfectly reasonable, and the ignore option exists exactly for situations like this.

Comment: But the ignore message is quite general, it cover many cases. If I choose to ignore it will be applied to all my views, right? So I have a risk of ignoring real problems in the future. I was looking for a way to prevent this message from the beginning, if that's possible (maybe it isn't).

Comment: These messages are per-property or per-view. If you ignore a warning it'll only apply to that particular property or view (depending on what type it is). You can see this by switching to a different account, and the message you're looking at will no longer be there.

Comment: Unfortunately the message is per-property. So my other views (apart of the redirects view) will be affected.